# How to bind 'this' to functions outside react class which is a callback from other component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I have a React Component such as :

```
function callback(params){..
// I need to use this.setstate but this callback function is called 
// from other component. How do I bind value of this here 
// 'this' of RespProperties
...
}

class RespProperties extends Component { ..
 ...
}
```

This callback function is called from some other component. How do I bind value of 'this' here so that it can use states of this component?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question.
I don't know if this is what you mean, but if you want to save the 'this' temporary variable, then just create a global array or single variable to store the 'this'.

```
var thisTemp;

function callback(params){..
// use variable here
thisTemp.blah();
...
}

class RespProperties extends Component { ..
//Assign this to thisTemp
thisTemp = this;
...
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't be answering the question if you don't know what the asker means, please ask clarifying questions in the comments...welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

You could separate this shared function, leaving it outside the components, then use `bind`:

```
function callback(params){
    this.setState({ works: true });
}

class RespProperties extends Component {
    state = { works: false }
    ...
    render = () => <button onClick={callback.bind(this)}>Click</button>
                                 // ^ here we use .bind(this) to... well...
                                 //   bind `this` so we can use it in the function xD
}

class SomeOtherComponent extends Component {
    state = { works: false }
    ...
    render = () => <button onClick={callback.bind(this)}>I'm from some other component</button>
}
```